# Change field type in model serializer without changing model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a string field with a corresponding model serializer. I'd like to change the serializer so that it now takes a list of strings for that field, but converts that list to a string internally.

Basically, `internal_repr = ','.join(input)`

I've tried changing the data type in the validate function, but I still get a validation error that it's not a string. Where should this change occur? Is it also necessary to override the serializer on that field to a `ListSerializer` with `child=CharField` specified?

Basic representation of the current situation:

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Serializer:

```
MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         fields = ('myfield')
```

I want to have the serializer take a list for myfield instead, and convert that to a string via ','.join()

Comment: It may help if you provide the code for your model/serializer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to add
`myfield = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), min_length=1)`
to the serializer to change the serializer type, as well as overriding the `to_internal_value()` and `to_representation()` methods to achieve this.

The code is now:

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Serializer:

```
MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   myfield = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), min_length=1)

   def to_internal_value(self, data):
        myfield_val = data.get('myfield')
        output = super(MyModelSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        output['myfield'] = ','.join(myfield_val)
        return output

   def to_representation(self, instance):
        myfield_val = instance.myfield.split(',')
        output = super(MyModelSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        output['myfield'] = myfield_val
        return output


   class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         fields = ('myfield')
```